# How do I configure a dataset WHERE clause for a bit column in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, dataset, where-clause, clause

I am using VB 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a database table with a column type "Bit".  The column name is "Inactive".  I have the dataset configured to show all of the data using a fill method.  What I want to be able to do is use a Fillby method to populate a DataGridView with rows of data where the checkboxes are not checked but do not know how to configure the "WHERE" clause.

If I write a WHERE clause like this, "WHERE Inactive = 1", I get the converse of what I want to achieve.  It shows the rows where the checkboxes have been checked.  I want to display all the rows that have not been checked.  "WHERE Inactive = 0" and "WHERE Inactive <> 1" do not work.

Is there a way of doing this in the dataset or must it be done in VB code?  If the latter, can someone provide an example as everything that I have tried gives me error messages such as "Integer cannot be converted to Boolean".

There must be a simple answer but after days of searching Google, I cannot find anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a query that includes Boolean data types, but the only valid `Boolean` operand types are the `=, != and <>` types. The value `TRUE` is equivalent to the number 1, and the value `FALSE` is equivalent to the number 0.
The following examples are of queries that compare a `Boolean` value against the values `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

```
SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE BoolProp = 1
SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE BoolProp = TRUE
SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE BoolProp <> FALSE
SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE BoolProp = 0
SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE BoolProp = FALSE
SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE BoolProp != 1
SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE BoolProp != FALSE
SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE BoolProp <> FALSE
```

[Source: MSDN Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394054(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response.  Before I read your answer, I found a solution.  If I configured the dataset Fill method WHERE clause to "WHERE (Inactive IS NULL)", it worked.